# Next.Js Image Component does not load image on localhost

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have setup the image domain on `next.config.js` but the image does not show on localhost. However image is loaded on vercel when code is pushed to production.

On localhost I get the following picture below. Image does not load.

[image]

On production, image can be seen

[image]

What should I do so that I can see the image on development?

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: [ 'd31wtm2rx76rut.cloudfront.net'],
    },
}
```

```js
<NextImage
    src=https://d31wtm2rx76rut.cloudfront.net/1604303981874
    alt="Khanna"
    layout="fill" />
```

Comment: When running the app locally, do the images use the same URL domain (`d31wtm2rx76rut.cloudfront.net`) as they do in production?

Comment: Yes, same URL domain for images

Comment: go to inspect -> network tab and check what response the image loading gives

Answer (score 2):

I have added **"unoptimized={true}** props and it's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For localhost, it works perfectly by adding things in `next.config.js`. After that restart the server.

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost']
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, but this is not ideal to push this config to production

Answer (score -1):

1. not sure about old nextjs versions but now image component in nextjs are like:

   `import Image from 'next/image'`

   ```
   <Image
   src="https://d31wtm2rx76rut.cloudfront.net/1604303981874"
   alt="Khanna"
   layout="fill" />
   ```

exports are correct. hope it works :)

though a quick fix can be adding ***unoptimized={true}*** props to image component (not recommended for production builds)

for more info check here [Nextjs Image Doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)