# setup next.config.js remotePatterns on localhost to get image from local API

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi i am trying to make a random image API, so when i visit the page  http://localhost:3000/random-img i get a random new Image.

My goal is to be able be able to use the url like this `<Image src="http//localhost:3000/random-img alt="something" fill>`

unfortuantely i get the error after trying to config my localhost

```
Error: Invalid src prop (http://localhost:3000/random-img) on `next/image`, hostname "localhost" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host
```

This is my config file, with an example that works and then this localhost
this is the way described in the documentation on the  https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "placeimg.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/720/480/**",
      },
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "localhost",
        port: "3000",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Here is "http//localhost:3000/random-img

```
function randomimg({ img }) {
  img = `img/${img}`;

  return (
    <>
      <img src={img} alt='lol' />


    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const getImg = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/");
  const imgName = await getImg.json();

  return {
    props: {
      img: imgName.image,
    },
  };
}

export default randomimg;
```

here is the api in pages/api/

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const fs = require("fs");

  const files = fs.readdirSync("public/img");

  const len = files.length;
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);

  res.status(200).json({ image: files[number] });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add the following to the next.config.js file:

   ```
   const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: true,
      images: {
          domains: ['127.0.0.1'],
      },
   };

   module.exports = nextConfig;
   ```
2. Use the url like this in your image component:

   ```
   import Image from 'next/image';
   const ImageComponent: React.FC = () => (
       <div>
           <Image src={'http://127.0.0.1:8000' + '/path/toImage.png'} alt={'alt'} width={28} height={28} />
       </div>
   );
   ```
3. Restart your nextjs server to make the changes take effect

Comment: `domains` is Deprecated since Next.js 14.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not valid for nextjs.14 i.e. it's deprecated and above. For Next js 14 and above, you must use [remotePatterns](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#remotepatterns) as per the Nextjs Docs. In my case, I had to comment out the protocol for it to work locally and specify the port NB: I have not tested it in production, but I'll come back to this once fully tested to update how it works.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
     remotePatterns: [
      {
         // protocol: "http",
        hostname: "127.0.0.1",
        port: "1337",
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: allright, thanks for updating

Answer (score 0):

this worked to me:

> For localhost, it works perfectly by adding things in next.config.js.
> After that restart the server.

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost']
  }
}
```

source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73176096